# Windows OS Architecture Book

Tags: .net, windows, operating-system

I have a background in programming and have done a little .NET but I feel that I would benefit from improving my understanding of the Windows Architecture. Can anyone recomend a good book that discusses the Windows Operating System from a technical perspactive, particulary it's architecture/design and how it works. Im not looking for a huge technical manual, just looking to get a general appreciation of how Windows works.

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Windows Internals Book](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963901.aspx) -- To delve inside Windows architecture and internals:

Comment: +1: This is *the* definitive resource.

Comment: Thanks very much, I'll give this one a read.

Answer (score 3):

- [Windows Architecture](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc768129.aspx)
- [Architecture of Windows NT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Architecture_of_Windows_NT)
- [Windows 2000 Architecture](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=21122)
- [Windows Programming/Windows System Architecture](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Windows_Programming/Windows_System_Architecture)

Comment: Thanks for the links, a good set of resources. I particularly like the Wikibook at the last link.

Answer (score 1):

Great question Dave.  I am mostly a web developer, but the book that really gave me a great understanding of .Net and I think is a must read (maybe a "prequel" for you) is [Jeffrey Richter's CLR via C#](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735627045).  It made me a better developer just from the fundamental way your construct your classes and how that impacts .Net, memory managment, multi-threading, etc.

Great fundamentals will lead you to books that some of these other folks have recommended.

I always recommend this book to anybody that is starting out and if you code along with it you will start to understand .Net a great deal.  I will ask around Windows Architecture front...

Good luck!